# Can we write to mongodb master through replica?

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing

I wounder if thous mongo nodes roles are transparent for end user or should we be aware about specific purpose of different nodes (master/slave)?

Comment: You can't write to anywhere in repset but to master.

Comment: @AlexBlex So, if i try it I'll get some king of exception and my request would't be forwarded to master automatically?

Comment: I fail to see how you could do id. Please update your question with what you did trying to write to secondary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to write through an application (like PHP/Java/NodeJS etc), mongodb driver for the language will automatically route the writes to primary (master) and reads will be redirected based on [Read Preference setting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/).

If you are connected to Mongo Shell and connected to Secondary (slave) it will give an exception but the write won't be redirected to Primary. To perform write through Shell, you must be connected to Primary.